# Chart.js - style legend: smaller circles

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js, linechart, chart.js2

I've create a line chart with chart.js. I changed the legend symbol form from rects to circles by using:

```
legend: {
  display: true,
  labels: {
    usePointStyle: true,
  },
}
```

I want to change the size of the circles. But according to the documentation this is only possible if I also change the font size:

> Label style will match corresponding point style (size is based on fontSize, boxWidth is not used in this case).
>   - https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html#legend-label-configuration

Does anyone know if there is another option to change the size? Or do I have to use *generateLabels()*.

Here is a [codePen](https://codepen.io/toxy1337/pen/rQRqrw) to take a look on that.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use the boxWidth option to influence the size of the point in the legend:

```
options: {
  legend: {
    labels: {
      usePointStyle: true,
      boxWidth: 6
    }
  }
}
```

read the [documentation of chartjs about legend](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html#legend-label-configuration)

Answer (score 3):

Chartjs 4.3.0:

in `options.plugins.legend.labels`

- `boxHeight` alone works for me and sets the image size (circle by default)
- `boxWidth` sets the distance to the following label text

[chartjs Legend Documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html#legend-label-configuration)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).